# Replace by regexp in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

```
Are you sure you want to delete "%lg_name%" group?
```

And in Javascript I have the variable `lg_name`. How can I replace `lg_name` string to `lg_name` variable? This regex shouldn't be related to the variable name. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'Are you sure you "%lg_name%" group?'.replace(/"%[^"%]*%"/, 'value');
```

Basically, you should find the `"%variable_name%"` token. You can do that using `/"%[^"%]*%"/` pattern. Then you can simply replace it, using the `replace` method of the your string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution, it replace the corresponding `%lg_name%` part with the variable name `lg_name`

```
'Are you sure you "%lg_name%" group?'.replace(/"%([^"%]*)%"/, function ($1,$2){return $2});
>>"Are you sure you lg_name group?"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   '11111'+(new RegExp("[a-z0-9]*"+lg_name+"[a-z0-9]*",'gi')).exec("Watch out for the rock!")[0]+'22222'
```